# I can't make an SCP file

Tags: qgis, scp

I am using QGIS 2.8 and am trying to create/load an SCP file in which to classify a Sentinel 2 image. It won't let me create an SCP file and keeps asking if I want to add missing fields to the shape file. If I answer yes or no, it still won't create an SCP file. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the plug-in but it doesn't help.

I tried to update to to 3.4 but that didn't work at all so I went back to 2.8. The SCP file is the training file to put the ROIs into. Without it I can't create ROIs.

Comment: What is an SCP file? Are you able to update to a more recent version of QGIS (current version is 3.4 (LTR) or 3.8)? Most people no longer use 2.8 so it will be difficult to find someone who can help you troubleshoot in that version.

Comment: I tried to update to to 3.4 but that didn't work at all so I went back to 2.8. The SCP file is the training file to put the ROIs into. Without it I can't create ROIs.